# Android - Webview as list view footer not working

Tags: android, html, android-listview, android-webview

I am trying to display web view as the footer for the list view.

Added the script to the html file and placed in assets folder
Created a layout with web view
Placed the web view as footer but I am not able to see the web view

WebView layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView  
        android:id="@+id/webview_footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

html file in assests folder:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="ym_1234" class="ym"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(e,t){if(t._ym===void 0){t._ym="";var m=e.createElement("script");
m.type="text/javascript",m.async=!0,m.src="//static.yieldmo.com/ym.min.js",(e.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||e.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).appendChild(m)}else t._ym instanceof String||void 0===t._ym.chkPls||t._ym.chkPls()})(document,window);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Fragment code where I added the footer:

```
ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
WebView web;
        LayoutInflater inflaterOf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        LinearLayout listFooterView = (LinearLayout)inflaterOf.inflate(com.philly.prosportsframework.R.layout.list_with_footer, null);
        web = (WebView)listFooterView.findViewById(R.id.webview_footer);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/news_footer.html");

        list.addFooterView(listFooterView);
```

I am only able to see the list but the the web view in the footer is not seen

Answer (score 0):

one quick question .... are u adding footer before setting up the adapter ?

```
list.addFooterView(listFooterView);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

it cant be read from your code ...

Comment: I tried to set text view as footer and it worked, I was able to see it. Then i changed on the place of textview layout to web view layout.I only pasted the code for adding the footer

Comment: ok ... so i created i simple app to see if its is even possible to display webview in footer and found out that it is ... also try to use View instead of linear layout ... if it wont work then try to use void addFooterView(View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)