# Android webview not loading the js but works in chrome browser

Tags: android-webview

I wanted to display a script which has ads in it. It works fine when we load in chrome browser and emulate in a device. But to doesn't work in Android

This the script:

```
 <div id="ym_12345" class="ym"></div><script type="text/javascript">(function(e,t){if(t._ym===void 0){t._ym="";var m=e.createElement("script");m.type="text/javascript",m.async=!0,m.src="//static.yieldmo.com/ym.min.js",(e.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||e.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).appendChild(m)}else t._ym instanceof String||void 0===t._ym.chkPls||t._ym.chkPls()})(document,window);</script>
```

I have a web view layout:

Code:

```
String html = 
                "<div id=\"ym_12345\" class=\"ym\"></div>" +
                "<script type=\"text/javascript\">(function(e,t){if(t._ym===void 0){t._ym=\"\";var m=e.createElement(\"script\");" +
                "m.type=\"text/javascript\",m.async=!0,m.src=\"//static.yieldmo.com/ym.min.js\",(e.getElementsByTagName(\"head\")[0]" +
                "||e.getElementsByTagName(\"body\")[0]).appendChild(m)}else t._ym instanceof String||void 0===t._ym.chkPls||t._ym.chkPls()})" +
                "(document,window);</script>";
wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview_ndn);
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        //wv.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true); 
        wv.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        //wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        wv.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I already tried placing then in assets folder and tried to load them, which I have mentioned in the below link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054913/android-webview-as-list-view-footer-not-working?rq=1#

Comment: Is this KitKat or previous? Have you looked at the logcat? There is a WebChromeClient.onConsoleMessage callback that might be called with a relevant error.

Comment: I tried a simple load url and it worked.